# Formula for getting specific rows from other sheets when using IMPORTRANGE()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I'm using IMPORTRANGE() to get values from another sheet.  I'm trying to find a formula that I can use for every row without having to type it in individually to get the following result:

For example, in row C3 I want to get the value for G2 from the other sheet.  Right now my formula is: 
`=IMPORTRANGE("16l-7o_K4DMv5QM8KEKA57l_Eqd7nDXEHKHUY7l5jx9Q","G2")`

C4 uses "G3", etc.  Is there a way to specify that the value will always be "G" + (the current row + 1)?  So C3 gets G2, C4 gets G3, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

> specify that the value will always be "G" + (the current row + 1)?

```
=INDIRECT("G"&ROW()+1)
```

> so C3 gets G2, C4 gets G3, etc.

```
=INDIRECT("G"&ROW()-1)
```

> I'm using `IMPORTRANGE()` to get values from another sheet

```
=IMPORTRANGE("16l-7o_K4DMv5QM8KEKA57l_Eqd7nDXEHKHUY7l5jx9Q", "Sheet1!G"&ROW()-1)
```

Comment: +1 And if you're looking to limit the number of calls to `IMPORTRANGE`, you can pull the whole column starting at the correct offset with `=IMPORTRANGE("16l-7o_K4DMv5QM8KEKA57l_Eqd7nDXEHKHUY7l5jx9Q", "Sheet1!G"&(ROW()-1)&":G")`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the hassle - this is what I need:
`CONCAT("G", (ROW() - 1)))`